# Modifying a JS Show/Hide to auto-show depending on page

Tags: javascript, css

I have a Javascript Show/Hide navigation bar on the website I'm currently working on that displays a sub navigation onclick. However, I would like the hidden subnavigation to automatically be displayed when the user is within that section of the site.

This is my JS:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    function HideContent(d) {
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
    }
    function ShowContent(d) {
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
    }
    function ReverseDisplay(d) {
    if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
    else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
    }
    //--></script>
```

And this is an example of the HTML:

```
    <nav class="sub-nav" id="company-nav" style="display: none;">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">People</a></li>
            </ul>
        <img src="/2013/img/blue-nav-arrow.png" border="0" alt="arrow" />
        </div>
    </nav>
```

This works fine from the homepage - where all subnavs are hidden by default - but, for example, if a user goes into the About page I want the company-nav sub-nav to be displayed by default.

I don't know if a JS or CSS will achieve this and I'm a bit rusty, so I'll appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Just create wrapper div in each page and then you can access it by `.home .sub-nav` or `.about-us .sub-nav`. In this case you don't need javascript

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is for individual pages have an `id` for the body tag, and through CSS, if the `id` is active, display the submenu.

Eg (about page):

HTML:

```
<body id='about'>
<nav id"company-nav">
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">History</a></li>
<li><a href="#">People</a></li>
</nav>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#about nav#company-id{
display:block;
}
```

Hope this helps.